# Integrating Sendgrid with Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, sendgrid

We have a site that's in Zend Framework. it uses a mailer called TransportFactory.php

It worked ok with exmail, but now we need to switch to SendGrid, and it's just not working, no matter the different guides we've looked at.

Does anyone have a similar setup and could share some code samples or tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that sendgrid (the email service) or Sendmail (the mail server?)

Comment: Sorry, yes that was a typo.  It's SendGrid.  I guess late on a Friday will do that to you.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approach you can have that mainly depends on how you code architecture is.

First, you could use their [SDK](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php). To do that, you can use an existing module [andrebian/sendgrid-transport-module](https://github.com/andrebian/sendgrid-transport-module) (see the sendgrid sdk in the `composer.json`).

Another approach that will be easier to implement as it complies with your existing code is to use sendgrid as an [SMTP server](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Email_Infrastructure/recommended_smtp_settings.html). This here is a [Sendgrid ZF1 example](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/zend.html) but that's the same settings in ZF2/3 anyway.

Comment: The SMTP server option is what we were trying to do.  No matter what, it refused to work.  We finally gave up and went with the original exmail config on port 25.  Something in the config somewhere was just not letting the mail out.  I had a separate terminal open with netstat running, and there was no activity on 587 at all.  Not sure where the issue was, but it was intensely frustrating.